# Oque significa esse erro? (Assign arrow function to a variable before exporting as module default import/no-anonymous-default-export)

Tags: javascript, react, eslint

Assign arrow function to a variable before exporting as module default  import/no-anonymous-default-export

```
export default () =>
    <header className="header">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Não entendo nada de React, mas me parece estar falando alguma coisa depois do `=>` esse código em HTML não era para estar dentro de um `{}`? do tipo: `default () => { codigo html }`, talvez com código HTML entre aspas dentro, algo como`{" .... "}`. Sei lá, só chute, pode ser não ser nada disso.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Erro de react como resolvo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/482658/erro-de-react-como-resolvo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atribua a arrow function a uma variável antes de exporta-la como default do seu módulo...

```js
const myVar = () => {
  return  <header className="header">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header> 
}

export default myVar;
```

Para exportar uma função você deveria declarar uma `function`:

```js
export default function myFunc() {
  return  <header className="header">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header> 
}
```

Comment: Isso que eu não entendo no curso eu aprendi que pode desse jeito!

Comment: Agora esse erro: Unexpected default export of anonymous function  import/no-anonymous-default-export

Comment: Desculpa, fiz na pressa e nem prestei atenção...
Mesmo exportando uma `function` você precisa nomea-la, corrigi já no exemplo.
Se você ler o erro ele reclama que a função não pode ser anônima, funções anônimas são basicamente funções sem nomes.

Comment: Aeeeeeee! agora sim cara valeu eu to duas semanas tentando arruma isso, tava quase desistindo. VALEU

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta, ajuda a quem esta passando pelo mesmo problema a encontrar a solução(sem ter de ficar lendo todos os comentários haha)

Answer (score 5):

### A causa do erro

Esse "erro" está relacionado a uma regra do [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import): [`import/no-anonymous-default-export`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md). A regra possui a seguinte definição:

> Reports if a module's default export is unnamed. This includes several types of unnamed data types; literals, object expressions, arrays, anonymous functions, arrow functions, and anonymous class declarations.
>
> Ensuring that default exports are named helps improve the grepability of the codebase by encouraging the re-use of the same identifier for the module's default export at its declaration site and at its import sites.

Em resumo, esta regra reportará um erro (ou warning) caso o `default export` não possua um nome, e a regra foi criada para encorajar o reuso do nome que foi exportado onde está sendo importado, por exemplo:

```
const fetchSomething = () => {};
export default fetchSomething;

// ---

import fetchSomething from './fetch'; // Posso usar qualquer nome, mas por convenção uso o mesmo
```

```
export default () => {};

// ---

import fetchAnything from './fetch'; // Aqui decidi chamar de "fetchAnithing", em outro 
// lugar posso chamar de outra coisa.
```

### Isso é danoso?

O código continuará funcionando com *unnamed exports*, mas o [ESLint](https://eslint.org) serve justamente para ajudar a ter padrões e convenções em um projeto, além de reportar *possíveis* erros.

### Como faço funcionar do jeito que está agora?

1. Você pode ignorar essa regra com `eslint-disable` no arquivo em questão:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default () => {};
```

2. Você pode desabilitar essa regra para qualquer arquivo, basta adicionar [nas configurações](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) (um arquivo `.eslint.*` ou um campo `eslintConfig` no `package.json`) que você quer desabilitar a regra:

```
{
  // ...
  rules: {
    // ...
    'import/no-anonymous-default-export': 'off',
  }
}
```

3. Você pode deixar a regra habilitada, porém permitir que *arrow functions* sejam exportadas sem um nome definido. Parecido com o passo 2, porém ao invés de desabilitar a regra apenas definimos uma opção extra dela:

```
"import/no-anonymous-default-export": ["error", {
  "allowArrowFunction": true,
}]
```

Mais detalhes desta regra podem ser encontrados no [link já citado](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md).